# How can I change the RSS feed address of my Wordpress blog?

Tags: rss, wordpress

I have redirected my Wordpress RSS feed (domain.com/feed) to FeedBurner, and made the FeedBurner feed the one publicly visible.

Still, the URL of the Wordpress RSS feed is the standard for any Wordpress blog (.../feed), and I have noticed that many readers are manually setting their RSS to this feed rather the FeedBurner url.

How can I change Wordpress' feed address so that it is private to the public, but still available to FeedBurner?

Answer (score 2):

You need to look for a plugin called Feedsmith. It does this perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

there are many ways to do that ,but this plugin do it easily for you , just enable and set security token:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/feed-changer/

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged - can you explain what it does and why it is good here? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer